# I am having problems with CSS getting ads to line up

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and I have three ads towards the bottom of my page. They appear but on there own line. I have tried everything from creating a floating div to removing divs. But I can't seem to figure out what part of the CSS isn't allowing these boxes to be straight across the page.

Here is the code for the three boxes:

```
<div class="wrapper margin-bot1">
    <div class="bg-3">
        <div class="indent">
            <div class="wrapper margin-bot">
                <img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/page1_img1.png" alt="" />
                <img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/logo_archilume.png" alt="" width="150" height="41" />
            </div>
            <ul class="ul-1">
                <li><a href="moreARCHI.html">Made in USA </a></li>
                <li><a href="moreARCHI.html">Expert Domestic Tech Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="moreARCHI.html">High-end installations</a></li>
                <li>Robust features</li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="more.html">Click to Order Now!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-3">
        <div class="indent">
            <div class="wrapper margin-bot">
                <img  src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/page1_img1.png" alt="" />
                <a href="moreGEN.html"> <img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/GenLume-Logo.png" alt="" width="103" height="41" /></a>
                <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <ul class="ul-1">
                <li><a class="test123" href="moreGEN.html">Quick solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="moreGEN.html">Turn-key applications</a></li>
                <li><a href="moreGEN.html">Certified</a></li>
                <li><a href="moreGEN.html">Competitive pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="moreGEN.html">Click to Order Now!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-3">
        <div class="indent">
            <div class="wrapper margin-bot">
                <img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/page1_img1.png" alt="" />
                <div class="extra-wrap">
                    <h4>DuraLume</h4>
                    <h5>Series</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="ul-1">
                <li><a href="more.html">Expert Domestic Tech Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="more.html">Made in USA </a></li>
                <li><a href="more.html">Custom solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="more.html">On-site Engineers</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="more.html">Click to Order Now!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to properly show the CSS but you can find the actual site here: http://www.webstertoolbox.com/

If you look below the Big banner you will see an ArchiLume, GenLume and DuraLume boxes that run vertically down the page. I want them to appear across the page.

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Frank G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy and fast to fix it.
Just change your css file named homeads.css on line 128:

```
.bg-3 
{
    background: url(../images/bg-4.png) left top no-repeat;
    width: 33%;  // Changed this from 100% to 33%
    height: 322px; //Changed from 268px to 322px
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;  // Added the float left
}
```

Cheers,
Thanos

**EDIT**: After doing the change above you will need to add a couple more changes to fix a couple of things that will get a bit misaligned.
Such as the right border will not be visible anymore. Below are the changes you will need to do to fix that as well.

On homeads.css line 33:

```
.main 
{
    width: 950px; // Reduced this to match with the parent's width
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

On sceleton.css line 25:

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12, .grid_13, .grid_14, .grid_15, .grid_16, .grid_17, .grid_18, .grid_19, .grid_20, .grid_21, .grid_22, .grid_23, .grid_24 
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    //margin-left: 5px;    Remove these 2
    //margin-right: 5px;   Remove these 2
}
```

**EDIT2:** The first box is getting pushed down a little bit. That is caused because on the first box you are missing a div <-> on the second and third box you have an extra div inside them.

```
<div class="wrapper margin-bot">
    <img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/page1_img1.png" alt=""><a href="moreGEN.html"> <img src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/duralume.gif" alt="" width="103" height="41"></a>
    <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div> // THIS IS THE EXTRA DIV
</div>
```

You have 2 choices here:

1) Add the div

```
<div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
```

to the first box

2) Remove that div from box 2 and 3.

Comment: that lined them up. Something so simple ugg. Here is mine with your code change http://www.webstertoolbox.com can you please tell me why they don't look like this site? http://websterdefined.com/erg1/

Comment: Hello Thanos, the last bit of code not sure I understand. I don't have a Sceleton.css page where am I supposed to change this? Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi Frank. You can find the sceleton.css here : http://www.webstertoolbox.com/skin/frontend/default/erglighting/css/skeleton.css  . Don't forget always keep a copy of the previous CSS or you can do what i do, comment the old styles and leave a date next to them just in case you want to search them up later on if something major breaks.

Comment: Cheers, glad i could help :) . Just check the rest of the pages to see if anything else broke - so we can fix it now that i am here :)

Comment: The one box is hanging off http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/ and they all seem a little out of wack any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: You still there? I can't get the boxes to line up right. Any suggestions to help?

Comment: You are missing the height:320px; at the homeads.css line 105 . I am still though trying to find why the first box is getting pushed a bit down...

Comment: Okay I updated the height. I'll wait to hear back to you on the one box. Its weird that its doing that.

Comment: Sweet, I figured it out. I was missing something in the html and the Duralume logo was to big. So I was able to figure it out and fix it

Comment: One suggestion i got now is to change at the homeads.css the height for .bg-3 from 320px to 270px and also on line 55 reduce the .margin-bot1  margin-bottom to 23px; .

Comment: Dude you rock I was trying to find that margin bottom because it was to long. Thank you so much! Now its perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

`.cms-home` class help you do not affect other pages layout. Add in your stylesheets:

```
.cms-home .wrapper {
    overflow: visible; //For big banner
}
.cms-home .bg-3 {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```